# Delete specific line numbers (passed as variable) from a file in linux

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two files. One having list of lines (which I don't require) say `Seqlist` and other text file (from which I intend to delete those corresponding lines) say `ContentFile`

```
$cat Seqlist         

3
4
7
10
345
7000
67001
.....
```

I used :

```
$ while read A; do sed -e "$((A)d" ContentFile; done < Seqlist >OUTPUT
```

but I am getting only the 3rd line number deleted. The rest lines are not getting deleted.

Comment: You might be helped by sed's -i flag; also, if you delete line  3, the new line 4 is the old line 5, so either reverse sort the line numbers or do some math...

Comment: sed -i will change the line numbers for the further modifications and thus the o/p will be erroneous.

Comment: What you posted is a syntax error and doesn't work at all; `"${A}d"` (curlies not parens and correctly matched) does run, but produces multiple copies of `ContentFile` each with only one deletion.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `d` to the end of each number in the line number file turns it into a `sed` script that deletes the specified lines from its input. Then it's easy:

```
$ sed -f lines_to_delete.sed file_with_lines.txt
```

The `sed` script may be created like this:

```
$ sed -e 's/$/d/' file_with_numbers.txt >lines_to_delete.sed
```

Comment: +1. to delete the correct lines, do a reverse numeric (and probably uniq) sort  (`sort -rnu`) on the line numbers first....when you delete a line, the numbering of subsequent lines will change.

Comment: @cas my solution doesn't have that problem. That's only a problem if you call `sed` multiple times, removing one line at a time, rewriting the file each time.

Comment: so it is.  i was thinking of ed.  I'll post an `ed` answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ed`:

```
printf "%s\n" $(printf "%sd\n" $(sort -rnu Seqlist)) w | ed ContentFile
```

This uses `printf` to build a list of commands (line-deletion commands from a unique, reverse sorted list of line numbers from Seqlist, and a "w" to write the modified file back to disk ) for `ed` to use to edit `ContentFile`

Comment: Note when using this `printf "%s\n" ..... | ed ...` method, any `ed` commands with spaces etc in them have to be quoted.  I find this a lot easier to use than `sed -i`, especially for appending or inserting lines.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of linenumbers fits in memory (but not necessarily the content file as for `ed`) you can do

```
awk 'FNR==NR{n[$0];next} !(FNR in n)' Seqfile ContentFile
```

If both files are (or can be) huge, and Seqfile is sorted

```
cat -n ContentFile | join -v2 -j1 Seqfile - | sed 's/^[0-9]* //'
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your script runs the the entire file through sed on the first pass so non of the other numbers has effect.

the easiest way to fix to is to buld up a list of lines and do a single pass through sed.

```
s=
while read a 
do s="$s$a d;"
done < Seqlist 
sed -e "$s" ContentFile  >OUTPUT
```

Comment: The other lines are also deleted, only they are not the lines that the OP thinks they are.